# CanCan skip authorization for some action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

I have problem with CanCan gem which I can't solve. In my controller I have action "confirm" which is a member route for "reservations" resource. I don't want to authorize resource by CanCan in this action so I do something like that in controller:

```
load_and_authorize_resource except: :confirm
```

But now I have error:

```
This action failed the check_authorization because it does not authorize_resource. Add skip_authorization_check to bypass this check.
```

How can I skip authorization for proper action in CanCan?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think something like this might work in your controller,

```
skip_authorization_check only: :confirm
load_and_authorize_resource except: :confirm
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yep, that was the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, using cancancan, it was as simple as replacing this

```rb
load_and_authorize_resource
```

with this

```rb
load_and_authorize_resource except: :webhook
```

and then the `/webhook` url worked without authorization